# How to block and subsctibe on a flux\mono

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I have a flux *A*, and i need to write a method *B func()*, such that this method returns another flux *B* so one can block on it(for testing purpoises). But, this flux *B* already have to subscribe on the flux *A*.
So, when somebody calls : *func().block();* in test, then the test should wait completion of flux *A*.
(the method *func()* must subsctibe on *A* in order to launch execution of flux *A*)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need `func()` at all or what you are trying to achieve. are `A` and `B` instances? return types? if the former, why can't you do `A.block()` in your test? if the later, what is `func()` input type and output type?

Answer (score 0):

Use toFeature() to wait for completion